# Django pagination with AJAX behaviour

Tags: python, ajax, django, pagination

I am looking for examples, tutorials, or even just directions on how I would implement pagination on list of comments with Django. And the list is just part of the web page, so I want to avoid refreshing the whole page when users change pages, thus AJAX. A perfect example is YouTube's comments section.

It's preferred if the solution uses Django's built-in pagination engine, but it doesn't have to be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django-endless-pagination is a really nice plugin for this. I've been using it for a while and have never had any issues with either the digg-style ajax pagination or the twitter style ajax pagination. Here's the link:

http://code.google.com/p/django-endless-pagination/

Comment: Awesome~ Thank Spike.
Let I take a look and see if it's a viable solution for me. Will let you know. Cheers.

Comment: Spike, the module looks quite promising for my purpose. But I got into a problem when I was trying it out. I think you might be able to help me.

The queryset that I am working with is **profile.feedbacks**

Comment: The previous comment is incomplete. 

Try again here...
The queryset that I need to work with is **profile.feedbacks**. I simply substituted _objects_ in _{% for object in objects %}_ with **profile.feedbacks**. When I ran my app, I got **"Invalid arguments for u'paginate' tag"** error. I think the cause is the dot notation, but shouldn't it work as long as I use a queryset?

Comment: hey ahmoo. Not sure exactly how to fix that, sorry... I'm guessing the for loop isn't what is causing the problem, since that's just a regular django tag. Your problem is probably in your {% paginate profile.feedbacks %} tag so try changing stuff in there. Or maybe use a {% with %} tag to get rid of the dot notation. Good luck.